Why does print() return the result of a class' default object.__str__(my_object) instead of the redefined my_object.__str__(my_object)?
I have the following class:
class UserAccount:
    name = None
    email = None
    password = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.email}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}, email: {self.email}"

I instantiated the class and called print() of my created user:
some_user = UserAccount
some_user.name = "John"
some_user.email = "test@test.com"
some_user.password = 'abc'
print(some_user)

When executing the code console returns the following:
<class '__main__.UserAccount'>
...which is equivalent of print(object.__str__(some_user)) output.
I expected the following output:
John, test@test.com
If I use print(some_user.__str__(some_user)) - then it works as expected. But simply passing the user object to print() invokes the standard __str__ instead of my redefined one, or my redefined __repr__. What could be the reason for it?

Your instantiation should be some_user = UserAccount()

As a tip, the leading <class part of the printout hinted at the problem. It's showing the class, not the instance.

because nowhere are you printing an instance of UserAccount, instead, you are printing an instance of type, i.e. the UserAccount class itself.
